# CLOCKS_PER_SEC, missing binary operator before token... [NFIQ 2.0]

Tags: c++, makefile, build, compilation, precompile

I'm trying to compile *NFIQ 2.0* source code by following the [official guide](https://www.nist.gov/services-resources/software/development-nfiq-20). In the final build step I get the following error.

```
FRFXLLCreateLibraryContext.cpp:72:5: error: missing binary operator before token "1000000"
 #if CLOCKS_PER_SEC == 1000
     ^
<builtin>: recipe for target 'FRFXLLCreateLibraryContext.o' failed
```

Here is information about the *gcc* version present

```
gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2)
```

and here is the ubuntu version info

```
uname -r
4.4.0-36-generic
```

What is causing the problem, and could it be solved by using a different compiler? Here is the full build log of make command

```
make
make -C ../libFRFXLL 
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/tutoivon/nfiq2/NFIQ2/libFRFXLL'
make -C src/libFRFXLL 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/tutoivon/nfiq2/NFIQ2/libFRFXLL/src/libFRFXLL'
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.o' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.o
r - FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.o
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.o' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'S/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLCreateContext.o FRFXLLCreateContext.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLCreateContext.o
r - FRFXLLCreateContext.o
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'S/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'S/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlace.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlace.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlace.o
r - FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlace.o
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'S/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'S/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLGetLibraryVersion.o FRFXLLGetLibraryVersion.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLGetLibraryVersion.o
r - FRFXLLGetLibraryVersion.o
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'S/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'FRFXLLExport.o' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLExport.o FRFXLLExport.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLExport.o
r - FRFXLLExport.o
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'FRFXLLExport.o' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'S/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSet.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSet.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLCreateFeatureSet.o
r - FRFXLLCreateFeatureSet.o
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'S/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'S/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLDuplicateHandle.o FRFXLLDuplicateHandle.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLDuplicateHandle.o
r - FRFXLLDuplicateHandle.o
make[2]: Warning: Archive '../../lib/libFRFXLL.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 'S/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo' will always be updated. Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLCreateLibraryContext.o FRFXLLCreateLibraryContext.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/time.h:41:0,
                 from FRFXLLCreateLibraryContext.cpp:35:
FRFXLLCreateLibraryContext.cpp:72:5: error: missing binary operator before token "1000000"
 #if CLOCKS_PER_SEC == 1000
     ^
<builtin>: recipe for target 'FRFXLLCreateLibraryContext.o' failed
make[2]: *** [FRFXLLCreateLibraryContext.o] Error 1
rm FRFXLLCreateContext.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.o FRFXLLDuplicateHandle.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSet.o FRFXLLGetLibraryVersion.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlace.o FRFXLLExport.o
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/tutoivon/nfiq2/NFIQ2/libFRFXLL/src/libFRFXLL'
Makefile:50: recipe for target 'src/libFRFXLL' failed
make[1]: *** [src/libFRFXLL] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tutoivon/nfiq2/NFIQ2/libFRFXLL'
Makefile:7: recipe for target '../libFRFXLL' failed
make: *** [../libFRFXLL] Error 2
```

Comment: Join me in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135255/room-for-nfiq-debugging if you like

Comment: Just noticed this too. Looks like this software is untested.

Answer (score 3):

**The NFIQ library has a bug here.**

It assumes that `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is a macro constant that can be used in preprocessor directives like `#if`, but it isn't! [It expands, in an implementation-defined way, to some expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)… and in GCC 6.3 at least (and apparently your version too) that expression is `((clock_t)1000000)`. [This expression will not work in a preprocessor directive](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b05213b0a331278).

Maybe the NFIQ authors only tested it in Visual Studio, and maybe Visual Studio *just so happens* to expand that macro to a basic literal. Or, maybe, they didn't test it at all.

Unfortunately there's no easy fix for that. They'd have to stop using `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` in a preprocessor directive altogether, but whether they can easily achieve the same thing with actual C++ code I don't know. Definitely one to raise with the authors.